# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Remote attribute onsubmit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've discovered that the `Remote` attribute wont fire if you navigate with your keyboard to the submit button, hence the onchange event for the remote attribute wont fire (at least not always) - Is there a workaround for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which rule you have use. The behavior would be the same.
If it doesn't validate, you probably have two issue to concern about:
1. the method `onkeyup` will fire only if you have submitted the form at least once.
**2**. maybe you have some JavaScript error somewhere while it try to run it (check if it has run with no error).
`remote` rule just like other rules, will fire 'onfocusout' and 'onkeyup' and 'onclick'. The latter will fired for checkbox and radio buttons.
`onkeyup` event will fired(on your key up) if you have submitted your form for once.
`onfocuseout` event will fired if you leave your `input` with your mouse or keyboard(with tap key).
And one last thing. all rules will be checked before you submit your form, even with `$(Form).submit()`